# Simple fool-proof Minecraft installer

Tags: batch

I am making a simple, (hopefully) fool-proof Minecraft installer for my friends, some of whom can't comprehend folders and zip files in addition to running a school-provided device, thus lacking certain functionalities (e.g., they can't install Java using the installer and must therefore fiddle around with zip files and environment variables if they were to do everything the installer would've done for them).

This started off with me listing some [QoL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_video_game_terms#QoL) mods I used, then helping them install those mods, then helping them to install a launcher to easily install those mods, and so on, gradually helping with the entire "pipeline". That was tiring and slow, so here I am.

I've set up an archive containing Java 17 and Prism Launcher pre-installed and pre-configured with the various QoL mods, and I now need to somehow get it to their device. I would've preferred Bash, but this needs to run on a stock Windows 10 device, potentially school-provided ones with policies that prevent normal installation of stuff, thus the use of archive files. Having them install Cygwin / WSL / Python / whatever would've defeated the entire purpose of this automation, since if they can figure that out, then they wouldn't have problems figuring out the "can't install Java" and "how do I download and install the mods" problems.

With Bash I have shellcheck, but I'm not sure what I can do about Batch other than trial and error. This did run in a Windows Sandbox environment (I did have to install vcruntime140, but I assume on a real device it would already be installed), but it was a lot of trial and error, given my unfamiliarity with the language (this is literally the first time I'm writing any Batch).

Would love some feedback about how I did in general, and what I can do to improve the script - best practices, etc.

`run.bat`:

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo(

set original_dir="%~dp0"

set /p "target_dir=Select an install location (Desktop=1, Documents=2, Downloads=3): "

if "%target_dir%"=="1" (
    set target_dir="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
) else if "%target_dir%"=="2" (
    set target_dir="%USERPROFILE%\Documents"
) else if "%target_dir%"=="3" (
    set target_dir="%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"
) else (
    echo Invalid option
    exit /b
)

move mc.tar.xz %target_dir%
cd %target_dir%

"%WINDIR%\System32\tar.exe" -xf mc.tar.xz
del mc.tar.xz
cd mc

cd PrismLauncher

echo( >> prismlauncher.cfg

hostname > tempfile
set /p temphostname=<tempfile
del tempfile
echo LastHostname=%temphostname% >> prismlauncher.cfg

set target_dir=%target_dir:\=/%
set target_dir=%target_dir:"=%
echo JavaPath=%target_dir%/mc/jdk-17.0.9+9/bin/javaw.exe >> prismlauncher.cfg

cd %original_dir%
start /b "" cmd.exe /c "del %~f0 & exit /b"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review context:

Both Author and Reviewer are not expert at batch.
My intent is that some new engineer,
also not expert at batch,
should be able to come along in a few months and maintain this.

---

## creating the .tar

> I've set up an archive containing Java 17 and Prism Launcher pre-installed and pre-configured with the various QoL mods

There is hopefully another script, not part of the submission,
which downloads these assets and builds the .tar from scratch.

Things change, java moves on to version 22, bugs get fixed.
You will want to be able to easily reproduce all the build steps
when one of them changes. This is a software
[life cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle)
process issue.

---

## problem statement, approach

The OP very helpfully includes some Review Context
explaining the motivation and the technical approach taken.
A summary of this should appear at the top as REMarks.
Or at least mention the URL of a ReadMe file.
End user should understand what will change and what things
(like a giant minecraft.tar plus this script) will be deleted.
I initially found the deletion surprising, but then it made sense.
With any luck deletion will only happen after successful install.

> (hopefully) fool-proof Minecraft installer

Excellent, I'm glad to see this philosophic perspective.

I didn't exactly see it in an explicit way in the code.
Some install scripts are divided into two phases:

1. readonly: gather / prepare / verify
2. execute

That is, we're going to need some assets,
maybe we verify their SHA3 hash,
we will need a writable install location that has space available,
and so on.
Knowing we have that in hand, then we can go do
destructive things like spam new folders onto the Desktop
or delete a downloaded asset.
IDK, maybe I'm being too paranoid, maybe this source code *does* do that,
and all that's missing is the occasional REMark describing
how things would unfold in the error case.

```
move mc.tar.xz %target_dir%
```

This seems to be the first place where things can go south.

In bash we might first verify the target is a `-w` writable `-d` directory --
[LBYL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use#Preventing_TOCTOU).
Here we forge ahead -- [EAFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use#Preventing_TOCTOU).

My review concern is whether we have bash `set -e` behavior here.
Will a `move` failure bail out?
Or will the script continue, nuking the .tar file and this script?
I'm not sure, and don't have a test system available,
but I *have* to believe that Author's Intent was immediate bailout.

---

## idempotency

The primary use case is a student encounters a computer
with no minecraft, runs the installer, and we're happy.
They visit the same computer the next day and they're still happy.

Suppose the following day they *believe* they're on a **new** computer,
but it turns out they're on the same one.
Maybe they forgot whether Downloads or Documents holds the game.
So they run the installer.
What happens?

Would installing to Downloads twice yield a working game?

Would installing to Downloads and then to Documents similarly work?
Would it leave us with two copies, and is that undesirable?
Maybe before prompting {1,2,3} the script should look around
for evidence of a previous install?
If Alice installs to Downloads, could Bob subsequently
install to his own Downloads on same machine?

### previous java

In a similar vein, do we care if a computer winds up
with both java 17 + java 19 installed?
Or three or four versions?
Could the script maybe look around and notice
there's a usable version already installed?
Yeah, yeah, I know, it's getting too complex, and out-of-scope.

### downloading assets

Rather than expecting a .tar in same directory as the .bat,
should this script perhaps have one or two hard-coded URLs
and obtain assets from internet as needed?

---

## blank line

I *think* this is equivalent to `/usr/bin/printf "\n"`:

```
echo(
```

I don't have a CMD.exe available to test that.

It appears to exploit a peculiarity in batch command parsing, one the
[vendor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo)
makes no explicit mention of.

Larry Wall asserts "there's more than one way to skin a cat!",
but not all developers agree with the Let a thousand flowers bloom
philosophy.
Be boring.
Following conventions is a good thing,
it makes software more maintainable.
Of the different variant approaches for emitting a newline,
the recommended one appears to be:

```
echo.
```

The vendor docs explain:

> Don't include a space before the period. Otherwise, the period appears instead of a blank line.

BTW, those docs also mention items like

> Applies To: Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8

which is something you might put in a REMark,
telling us the one or two OS versions you have tested against.

---

## arcane invocations

```
set original_dir="%~dp0"
```

Experienced batch hackers would
[recognize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290765)
this immediately. For everyone else, consider calling
this `run_bat_dir` or perhaps `drive_path_dir`.

```
set target_dir=%target_dir:\=/%
set target_dir=%target_dir:"=%
```

I bet something really cool happened there, something essential.
I don't know what it is, and R / APL / batch punctuation
is notoriously difficult to google for.
Please show us `REM foo"bar" --> foobar`,
or a better example of what this pair of lines is intended to do.

```
... %~f0 ...
```

Consider assigning that to `batch_file_path` and using *that*,
just for its documentation value.

## names

Using a slightly obscure directory name of `mc/`
is perhaps deliberate, so as not to attract too much
attention from adults.
If not, prefer `minecraft/` and `minecraft.tar.xz`.

Consider incorporating a
[version number](https://semver.org)
in the .tar file's name.

## setting LastHostname

```
hostname > tempfile
set /p temphostname=<tempfile
del tempfile
```

This seems more painful than necessary.

Is it possible to `echo` without a trailing CRLF ?

Alternatively, if we tacked on a trailing `\` backwhack
with `echo LastHostname=\`,
would PrismLauncher accept a multiline config option?
If so, we could just finish up with
`hostname >> prismlauncher.cfg`

---

## uninstaller

Perhaps we want one?
Or manual directions for uninstalling?

---

## test suite

Consider putting some of those arcane invocations
into one-line unit tests, which know the correct
answer and so can display a Green bar.

Consider writing an idempotency integration test
which abuses some poor computer in ways I suggested above,
with multiple attempted installs and then some
automated verification that all is well.

Such tests will come in handy when the school
upgrades to a future windows release.

---

This script achieves its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate maintenance tasks on it
to an engineer who is well versed in Batch
and has test systems available running the targeted operating system(s).
After some of the proposed enhancements have been incorporated,
I would be willing to delegate maintenance tasks
to a junior dev who has test systems available.

Comment: Thank you for the review. Answering some of the questions: 1) Modern Minecraft runs only on Java 17, and in my experience reading logs, loading a higher version just makes it somehow drop to Java 17 compatibility level, or straight up erroring. But yes, I do have a way to reproduce the minecraft tar. 2) `echo.` fails in case of [a file with that name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379940). For some reason, `echo(` doesn't fail. [1/3]

Comment: 3) `echo` takes no switches and always ends with CRLF, and I was looking for an equivalent of Bash `echo "LastHostname=$(hostname)"`, which doesn't seem to exist, with suggestions for using a tempfile instead, as I've done. [2/3]

Comment: 4) The arcane invocations are to strip quotes I added, originally to avoid problems with path with spaces, but the config file doesn't like quotes and Windows style paths (it seems very rudimentary, like an ini file, so I expect it won't like multiline stuff either), so I have to remove them again and flip the slashes. It's basically [string substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13210880) to flip the slash and get rid of the quotes. 5) I do provide additional information text regarding how to use the installer, uninstalling is simply deleting the folder. [3/3]

Comment: zomg what a landmine of a language product, where Best Practice is to do the opposite of what vendor's docs advise. Ok, I understand, thank you kindly. For documentation purposes consider defining a two-line helper function, and then you can `call:flip_slashes_and_strip_quotes`. Or just add a `REM` to that effect. In general, it is clear you have put _so much_ research into the details, and it's worth capturing the relevant reference URLs in comments or in an accompanying ReadMe. Based on our discussion, the OP source code is clearly just the tip of the iceberg.